# maps in Struts 2 in JSP

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2

I have a map:

`private Map<Long, String> map;`

It also has a getter. 
Now I'm iterating on users list in JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="userList" status="row">
    ...
</s:iterator>
```

The key to the map is user's id. How can I retrieve the value for current user's id?
I'm trying something like that:

```
<s:param name="groupsForUserOnList" value="%{map[id]}" />
```

but it doesn't work. Getter is being called, I checked in debugger, but no value is retrieved (probably it is a problem with the key). Please help me

Comment: That's not the same situation my friend

Comment: Not a dup. @sztukers How the `userList` looks like? Can you show more jsp code.

Comment: Could you try `var="myUser"` in `iterator` tag then `<s:param name="groupsForUserOnList" value="map[#myUser.id]" />`.